# How to lock MySQL table(s) from update until two separate select statements execute

Tags: mysql, sql, database, locking, innodb

I need to lock and perform two select statements on two MySQL/InnoDB tables. Both tables have related row name `updateId`.

```
SELECT ..., updateId FROM Table1 WHERE ...
SELECT ..., updateId FROM Table2 WHERE ...
```

I need to prevent updates, inserts or deletions (any modifications on the tables) until both SELECT statements execute. 
Basically I want to prevent any changes to `updateId` row between the two statements.

I was looking at `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` but I'm just a bit unclear how it works.

Comment: which db engine you are using. innodb ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen  it's written in his question, Innodb

Comment: ups, sorry. I think its to early for me :-). You can use: **START TRANSACTION;** .... your queries ... **COMMIT;**. this will only set a write lock and other queries can read from it.

Comment: @BerndBuffen are you saying I should do START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT even if I execute only SELECT statements? Will that lock changes from other update/insert transactions?

Comment: @MatejUkmar - Yes.  The lock is released at `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`)

Answer (score 2):

The other process can!! write, but the first process works wit the data at the moment from the transaction.

here is a sample with transaction

```
MariaDB [trans]> select * from table1;
+----+-------------+
| id | field1      |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | table 1 -1  |
|  2 | table 1 - 2 |
+----+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [trans]> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [trans]> select * from table1;
+----+-------------+
| id | field1      |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | table 1 -1  |
|  2 | table 1 - 2 |
+----+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)


                    CLIENT 2:
                    MariaDB [trans]> update table1 set field1 = 'new value' where id = 1;
                    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.003 sec)
                    Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

                    MariaDB [trans]> 






MariaDB [trans]> select * from table1;
+----+-------------+
| id | field1      |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | table 1 -1  |
|  2 | table 1 - 2 |
+----+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [trans]> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [trans]> select * from table1;
+----+-------------+
| id | field1      |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | new value   |
|  2 | table 1 - 2 |
+----+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [trans]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
blah, blah, blah
UPDATE/INSERT/etc (if desired)
COMMIT;
```

`FOR UPDATE` means "I *might* change the rows in this `SELECT`, so keep your hands off!"